# Unable to establish socket session, No route to host On RouterOS

Tags: php, router-os

I am trying to communicate with a Mikrotik Router OS Via PHP as below

```
 private function openSocket(): void
    {
        $options = ['ssl' => $this->config('ssl_options')];
        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $proto = $this->config('ssl') ? 'ssl://' : '';
        $socket = @stream_socket_client(
            $proto . $this->config('host') . ':' . $this->config('port'),
            $this->socket_err_num,
            $this->socket_err_str,
            $this->config('timeout'),
            STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,
            $context
        );
        if ($socket === false) {
            throw new ConnectException('Unable to establish socket session, ' . $this->socket_err_str);
        }
        stream_set_timeout($socket, $this->config('timeout'));
        $this->setSocket($socket);
    }
```

Here, the PORT is one of  `public const PORT = 8728; public const PORT_SSL = 8729;`.  and The IP address is `192.168.0.1`

Connection worked flawlessly on localhost.

Now when I tried to access the RouterOS from a php script hosted on an online server I am constantly getting the error `Unable to establish socket session, No route to host` from the php script.

Please, how can I resolve this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to connect to the public address, not the private address.

Comment: Private addresses can't be reached from the Internet, because they're *private*.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much for your input. How can I generate the public address? Any idea? I'm building this for a client, I'm not the owner of the Router.

Comment: You can use the WhatIsMyIP API: https://www.whatismyip.com/api/

Comment: @Barmar I see.Thanks so much. I will give that a shot

Comment: you need create a redirection port to Mikrotik from ISP Router. This is a destination nat